# A simplified 0/1 Knapsack problem with multiple items allowed in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, recursion, knapsack-problem

I have a problem which is a simplified version of the knapsack problem. It goes like this. There is a store and we have a list of items in that store. Let's say like this,
Store has 2 types of products Normal products and limited products.

**Product Class**

```
class Product:
    """ 
    A class to provide abstraction for products availabel in the system.
    unless the product is a Limited_product its supply is infinite
    """
    product_counter = 0

    ##### Part 1.1 #####
    def __init__(self, name, price):
        """ Constructor for initialization """
        
        self.name = name
        self.price = price
        self.id = Product.product_counter
        Product.product_counter += 1

    def __str__(self):
        """ returns a string representation of a product """
        return "<{}> {} - {}$".format(self.id, self.name, self.price)

    def __repr__(self):
        """ represents the class object as a string """
        return "PRODUCT <{}>".format(self.id)
```

**Limited Product Class**

```
class Limited_Product(Product):
    """
    A child class of the parent Product class
    Represents a Limited product where the quantity is depreceating
    """

    ##### Part 1.2 #####
    def __init__(self, name, price, amount):
        """ Constructor for initialization """
        super().__init__(name, price)
        self.amount = amount

    def __str__(self):
        """ returns a string representation of a limited product """
        return "<{}> {} - {}$ ({} left)".format(self.id, self.name, self.price, self.amount)

    def decrement_amount(self):
        """ decrement the amount of available product """
        self.amount -= 1

    def get_amount(self):
        """ returns the amount available from the product """
        return self.amount
```

Now we are given a list of products and the maximum amount a customer can spend.

============================

Product - Price

A - 20$

B - 7$

C - 1$ (2 left)

============================

And we have to find out what is the minimum amount left after the customer buys a sequence from these items using both recursion as well as iteratively by completing the given two functions. **These functions are given so I cannot write in a different method**.

**As an example:**

```
>>> store.so_rich(45)

output - 1
```

You have 45 dollars to spend. The optimal solution is buying six B items and two C items. This will leave you with 45 - 7 * 6 - 1 * 2 = 1 dollars left. The least amount of money left is 1 since there is no way to spend all of the money. (although C’s price is 1$, you have purchased all of them already!)

```
>>> store.so_rich(61)

0
```

You have 61 dollars to spend. You can spend all of them by buying two A and three B (20 * 2 + 7 * 3 = 61). So the least amount of money left is 0.

**The two functions that I wrote**

```
    def so_rich(self, money):

        # suppose you haven't seen any product yet
        # the only possible amount of money left is "money"
        # this is a set to record the possible money left
        left = set([money])

        # get products
        lst = list(self.warehouse.inventory.values())
        print(str(lst))
        for product in lst:

            # a temporary set to save the updates of "left"
            # you don't want to modify the set you're iterating through
            tmp_left = set()

            for m in left:
                # update tmp_left
                if type(product) != Limited_Product:
                    new_left = m
                    #new_left -= product.price
                    while product.price <= new_left:
                        print(new_left, product.name)
                        tmp_left.add(new_left)
                        new_left = new_left - product.price
                else:
                    # handle limited product
                    new_left = m
                    product_count = product.amount
                    while product.price <= new_left and product_count > 0:
                        print(new_left, product.name)
                        tmp_left.add(new_left)
                        new_left = new_left - product.price
                        product_count -= 1
            left = tmp_left
            print(left)

        return min(left)

    def so_rich_recursive(self, money):

        # get products
        lst = list(self.warehouse.inventory.values())
        
        def helper(lst, money):
            
            # base case
            if not lst:
                return money
            
            cur_min = money
            product = lst[0]
            if type(product) != Limited_Product:
                tmp = money
                while product.price < tmp:
                    cur_min = tmp
                    tmp -= product.price
                    print(cur_min, product.name)
            else:
                tmp = money
                product_count = product.amount
                while product.price <= tmp and product_count > 0:
                    cur_min = tmp
                    tmp -= product.price
                    product_count -= 1
                    print(cur_min, product.name)
            money = money - cur_min
            print("-----", money)
            lst.pop(0)
            return helper(lst, money)
        
        return helper(lst, money)
```

I cannot understand why the above code written by me does not work. Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: What error are you getting while executing the code? for this line `for m in left:` anyways you are passing a number, so there will be only one item in that `set`. So what is the point of using the `for` loop.

Comment: @Praveen here the set will be updated so that it has more than 1 item when the function executes. It does not give an error. It does not give the correct answer.